# SQL Join and count relations

Tags: sql, postgresql

Having a PostgreSQL query problem, and wondering if there's an efficient way to get this in a single query. Let's take the following simple table structure. Think of it as the traditional many to many relationship.

users <-> user_collections <-> collections

Given a users id, I'd like to first get all of their collections. This is the simple part for which I have a query:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, c.description, c.created_at, c.updated_at
FROM collections c 
JOIN user_collections uc ON c.id = uc.collection_id
WHERE uc.user_id = $1
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

So for example:

```
users
id | email
1  | user1@example.com
2  | user2@example.com
3  | user3@example.com

user_collections
id | user_id | collection_id
1  | 1       | 1
2  | 2       | 1
3  | 3       | 1

collections
id | name    | description
1  | Example | Demo collection
```

In the above case, querying for collections for user one would yield the first collection. **However** I'd also like to get a count of how many users are associated with each collection. In this case, a total count of 3, since all three members share this collection. A member count if you will. Is there a sensible way to do this in one query, or is two probably better?

Comment: Please provide sample dataset . which will make easy to understand your requirement.

Comment: Apologies, I added some sample data in an effort to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use here a **correlated sub query** to get the corresponding total user of that collection [Correlated sub query help https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-correlated-subqueries/]

```
SELECT c.* , (select count(user_id) from user_collections sc where sc.collection_id=uc.collection_id) as GroupCount
FROM collections c 
JOIN user_collections uc ON c.id = uc.collection_id
WHERE uc.user_id = $1
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach to using correlated subquery is to pre-calculated the number of users in each collection, then join it to your existing query.

i.e.

```
with collection_counts as (
    select 
        collection_id
        , count(1) as collection_count
    from user_collections
    group by collection_id
)
SELECT 
    c.id
    , c.name
    , c.description
    , c.created_at
    , c.updated_at
    , cc.collecion_count
FROM collections c 
JOIN user_collections uc ON c.id = uc.collection_id
join collection_counts as cc on c.id = cc.collection_id
WHERE uc.user_id = $1
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, c.description, c.created_at, c.updated_at,
       COUNT(*) as num_users
FROM collections c JOIN
     user_collections uc
     ON c.id = uc.collection_id
GROUP BY c.id
HAVING COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE uc.user_id = $1) > 0
ORDER BY created_at DESC;
```

That said, it might be faster to do:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, c.description, c.created_at, c.updated_at,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM user_collections uc
        WHERE c.id = uc.collection_id
       ) as num_users
FROM collections c 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM user_collections uc
              WHERE c.id = uc.collection_id AND
                    uc.user_id = $1
             )
ORDER BY created_at DESC;
```

This would be faster for two reasons:

- It avoids the outer aggregation.  Aggregations on larger data are generally more expensive.
- It calculates the count only for the collections that are in the result set.

This can also make use of indexes on the table -- which if you care about performance, you should have.